# Set value in pandas multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I'm trying to set a value in a cell of a pandas multi index dataframe using the suggestions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23108889/set-value-multiindex-pandas). But because I have a datetime as the index, I can't seem to access the particular cell. Is there an efficient way to do this without any warnings like `SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`.

```
import pandas as pd

y = pd.DataFrame(data = 0,
                 index = pd.date_range('2021-08-01', '2021-09-15', freq='D'),
                 columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['purple', 'green'], 
                                                       ['fish', 'goat', 'cat'],
                                                       ['gamma', 'alpha', 'beta']]))

y.loc[y.index=='2021-08-03',('green','cat','gamma')] = 34
# y[[('2021-08-03','green','cat','gamma')]] = 34
# y['2021-08-03']['green']['cat']['gamma'] = 34

y.head()
```

Comment: `y.loc['2021-08-03',('green','cat','gamma')] = 34` works for me

Comment: what python version do you use?

Comment: Python 3.9.7, pandas 1.3.4

Answer (score 0):

you can use **iloc** or **loc** functions to access and modify any cell across the dataframe

```
y.iloc[2,4]=45   #for purple, goat alpha
```

or

```
y.loc["2021-08-03",("purple","goat","alpha")]=45
```